# Adding filtered attributes

Tags: attributes, blocks

I am struggeling to set a certain set of attributes to my product page. I want to list certain attributes directly under the "short description".

I already copied and edited the attributes.phtml -> attributescontrollers.phtml

This file has a filter set:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct()?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="Table">
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $test_value = $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])); ?>
    <?php if (strpos($test_value,'Color') !== false) { ?>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
            <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
            </div>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This way only the Color attribute is listed (will be a longer list). I also created the blcok I wanted in my catalog.XML

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="compatibility" template="catalog/product/view/attributescontroller.phtml"/>
```

Once again, this works fine if I call it outside of the view block.

How can I add this block just under the short description?

Comment: if the provided answer helped you, please accept the answer by clicking the tick so that it turns to green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to edit the `.../template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and find the line `<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>` and place the following code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('compatibility') ?>
```

where this short description condition ends i.e. `<?php endif; ?>` and if you want to show this block only if short description is available then add it before `<?php endif; ?>`.